# Что не так в коде данной программы?

Tags: c#

Программа должно находить целое и остаток, используя лишь сложения и вычитания.При появлении остатка программа выдаёт следующее, хотя без остатка работает нормально(например, 15 на 3 делит нормально)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Training
{
   class cmon
    {
        public int num;
        public int k, count;

        public void enter()
        {
            Console.Write("Введите делимое: ");
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите делитель: ");
            k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        public void del()
        {
            do
            {
                num -= k;
                count++;
            }
            while (num  != 0);
        }

        public void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Целое: " + count);
            Console.WriteLine("Остаток: " + num);
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cmon h = new cmon();
            h.enter();
            h.del();
            h.print();


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут вообще очень много ошибок.

Comment: @DanielOlivo - нет, ошибок немного: `while(num > 0)` а после цикла, если остаток меньше нуля, надо прибавить обратно делитель.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void del()
{
    for (count = 0; num >= k; ++count, num -= k) {}
}
```

`num` и `k` лучше сделать `uint`

Comment: что-то накручено с последней строчкой. `count = 0; num >= k;`

Comment: @Igor да вы правы, это я что накрутил, сейчас исправлю